# Play Framework onLoadConfig

Tags: playframework

In the GlobalSettings.scala, I can override the onLoadConfig(...) method and tie that in my application.conf. The method signature is:

```
def onLoadConfig(config: Configuration, path: File,
    classloader: ClassLoader, mode: Mode.Mode): Configuration
```

What are these parameters and how is this method called? Is it called when I start my play server? What and how are these parameters injected into this method?

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.7/api/java/index.html#play.api.Configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [blog](http://www.codeblog.it/en/snippet/scala/2013/05/23/playframework-2-load-different-config-according-current-mode), I think that this could be useful for you

If you want different configurations for a web application, when you are developing it, i.e. development ,test, production, ... The way to implement it easilly in play framework is using:

override def onLoadConfig(config: Configuration, path: File, classloader: ClassLoader, mode: Mode.Mode): Configuration

You have only to override onLoadConfig in the global object with this code and after you'll have loaded a default application.conf, and a conf file for every mode.

```
 object Global extends GlobalSettings with Loggable {

  override def onLoadConfig(config: Configuration, path: File, classloader: ClassLoader, mode: Mode.Mode): Configuration = {
    val modeSpecificConfig = config ++ Configuration(
      ConfigFactory.load(s"application.${mode.toString.toLowerCase}.conf"))
    super.onLoadConfig(modeSpecificConfig, path, classloader, mode)
  }

}
```

Now play will load those files, application.conf is ever loaded, and after is also loaded the right file 
for current mode, which override default configurations if they are present, the files which are loaded are:

application.conf
application.dev.conf
application.prod.conf
application.test.conf